# nuxt3 import 'node_modules/@apollo/client/core' is not supported resolving es modules

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, nuxtjs3

When I use Nuxt3 + Vue Apollo + GraphQL, running  `yarn build`  and `node .output/server/index.mjs`, getting the error:

```
Directory import '/mnt/d/projects/.output/server/node_modules/@apollo/client/core' is not supported resolving ES modules imported 
from /mnt/d/projects/.output/server/chunks/app/server.mjs
Did you mean to import @apollo/client/core/core.cjs?
  at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
  at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:412:17)
  at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:932:10)
  at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1044:11)
  at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:422:30)
  at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:222:40)
  at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
  at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36)
```

This is my environment and configuration:

- Operating System: Linux version 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2
- Node Version: v16.13.0
- Npm Version: v8.1.0

package.json:

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.6.2",
    "@vue/apollo-composable": "^4.0.0-alpha.17",
    "@vue/apollo-util": "^4.0.0-alpha.17",
    "graphql": "^15.8.0",
    "graphql-tag": "2.12.6",
    "nuxt3": "3.0.0-27470397.9ebea90",
    ...
  },
}
```

nuxt.config.ts:

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt3';

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  build: {
    transpile: ['tslib', '@apollo/client', 'ts-invariant/process'],
  },
  ...
});
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: This question looks heavily similar to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72258630/nuxt3-cannot-find-module-node-modules-graphql-language-printer-imported-from

Comment: Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/5023